# In C# Why Some NuGet Packages are named as Repacked for example Unity.Repacked?

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I have seen multiple Nuget packages with same naming convention. Like Unit.Repacked and Newtonsoft.Json.Repacked and Specflow.Repacked?

Is there any specific reason for putting postfix as Repacked?

Comment: To my limited understanding, some packages can be re-released without changes (to the package's functionality) to accommodate the new `PackageReference` system.  It's the same package, just with new package metadata.  Other reasons to repackage can include updating dependencies that don't have an effect on the package's functionality.  There might be more to it than this.